# Adding Text over images in html

Tags: html, css

I recently got a hand on this snippet `Visit` https://codepen.io/artistic18/pen/xyLmpq and thought of using this but the problem is that whenever I am trying to add some text it's getting added in the background and I am not able to add it above the last layer. Moreover Nav Bar animations are also not working.

Project Link- `Visit` https://github.com/Artistic18/MyPortfolio
Feel Free to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Add a paragraph at the end of the HTML (`<p class="text...`) and then in CSS : `.text{ color:white;mix-blend-mode: exclusion;}`